# How can I increase the post count for custom post types only?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, loop, archives, options

I have the page count set to the default 10 in my reading settings menu.

[screenshot-with-shadow.jpg http://img257.imageshack.us/img257/5788/screenshotwithshadow.jpg](http://img257.imageshack.us/img257/5788/screenshotwithshadow.jpg)

However, I use my template `archive.php` file for all post types, including `posts` and `books`

How can I change the loop so that when searching `books` it will show 30 books in the archive page instead of showing the default 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
add_action('parse_query', 'wpse32932_parse_query'); 
function wpse32932_parse_query( $wp ){
    if( $wp->is_post_type_archive ):
        $wp->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 30;
    endif;
    return $wp;
}
```